# How to force watch to run under bash

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, function, watch

The problem is that when watch is executed it runs `sh` and I get this error:

```
sh: 1: func1: not found
```

here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

func1(){
  echo $1
}

export -f func1

watch func1
```

Comment: Can you give what command you actually run?

Comment: @Gnouc instead of echo $1 i have a bit long script so i don't know ..

Comment: I mean how did you run your ssh command?

Comment: @Gnouc ./bin/myfunc.sh

Comment: Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where is `ssh` coming into this? I see no `ssh` anywhere

Comment: @Patrick sorry my bad, i meant sh not ssh

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The default shell for `watch` is `/bin/sh`. Shells will not inherit exported variables or functions from other types of shell.

If your system does not symlink `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` (or your current shell) then you can instruct `watch` to exec your shell by using `-x` or `--exec`:

```
watch -x bash -c "my_func"
```

or

```
watch --exec bash -c "my_func"
```

This is different to `watch bash -c "test_watch"` (excluding the `--exec`) as it doesn't use `/bin/sh` to spawn the child process (in this case, `bash`), maintaining `bash` all the way down. As caveated in other answers, this can get messy if exporting functions that are highly coupled to the current environment (i.e. requiring other variables or functions).

---

An example:

```
test_watch() { echo 'Working!'; }
export -f test_watch
watch --exec bash -c "test_watch"
```

gives the familiar

```
Every 2.0s: bash -c test_watch                                   Thu Mar 31 11:15:56 2016

Working!
```

Comment: Only `watch -x bash -c my-func` yes this work for me on Ubuntu Server 16.04 - while others don't. Thanks a ton!

Comment: what does the `-f` do? just for functions?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian correct. See `help export` in Bash for the answer: `-f   refer to shell functions`

Answer (score 11):

Ok, so there are a few issues with your approach.

You are exporting a function, which is not portable between shells. `watch` executes its commands with `/bin/sh`, which on your system is not `bash`. And whatever shell it is, it doesn't respect function exports, so you get the error.

Secondly, you can change your command to something like `watch bash -c 'func1'`, but this may not work well either.
The reason here being that any variables set by the script won't be available to the function. You might be able to export the ones it needs, but that starts getting messy.

The safest solution is to put `func1` in a script by itself and call that script.

In short, try:

```
watch bash -c func1
```

Comment: It is very CPU intensive in case function is defined in `.bash_profile`

Comment: @VarunAgw, that is a good point. However, it is a great command for monitoring things in an environment where the `.bash_profile` file is relatively empty. However, I did want to run an alias that was in my `.bash_aliases` file (_sourced through my `.bashrc`_), so I ended up adding the `-i` flag to bash as well. I thought that might help someone:
`watch bash -ic "func1; alias1; func2; …"`

Comment: Only `watch -x bash -c my-func` work for me on Ubuntu Server 16.04 - while others don't.

Answer (score 4):

Why run `watch` from inside your script? Why not have this shell script:

```
$ cat func1 
#!/bin/bash

func1(){
  echo $1
}

func1 $1
```

... and then run it like so ...

```
$ watch func1 foo
```